# Controller required by directive can't be found in Angular.JS

Tags: angularjs, controller, directive

As the title indicates, I get this error with a parent custom directive (that defines a controller) in a ng-view that replaces the content with a template containing a child custom directive (that requires the parent controller) and ng-repeat.

I have created [a simple plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/S3nR1BFbwbPZaujnAXaY?p=preview) to illustrate my problem:

Main template:

```
<div class="ng-view">
  <div data-my-parent></div>
</div>
```

Route:

```
  $routeProvider.when( '/', { 
    template: '<span>View loaded.</span>', 
    controller: [ '$scope', function( $scope ) { 
      $scope.items = [ 'item1', 'item2' ];}]});
```

Parent directive:

```
.directive( 'myParent', function() {
  return {
    replace: true,
    template: '<ul><li data-my-child data-ng-repeat = "item in items"></li></ul>',
    controller: [ '$scope', '$element', '$attrs', function( $scope, $element, $attrs ){}]};})
```

Child directive:

```
.directive( 'myChild', function() {
  return {
    require: '^myParent',
    link: function( scope, element, attrs, controller ) {}};})
```

Basically, I think it has to deal with the ad hoc transclude system (for ng-repeat) but I don't know exactly if it's bad coding or a bug. What is the best way to get rid of this error? Require optional controller with '?' ?

Answer (score 2):

`ngView`'s content is replaced with the route's template, so your `<div data-my-parent></div>` get's lost.

Comment: I know that, it's not the problem. I did it on purpose. The fact is that the content replaced is called first and throws an error.

Comment: No, it **IS** the problem. The problem is that `ngView` removes its content and thus the element with `myParent` is not found (since it is removed from the DOM). If you remove the `ngView` it works fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/87A6r166TNX3F0SVmWr4?p=preview

Comment: I know that too... This is just an example and I have to use ng-view in my project with a predefined content that contains a directive. Before routing happens, myParent directive should be generated without error and THAT IS the all point of the question. If an error occurs, I think it has to deal with the process of removing myParent directive from the DOM because of the ng-view before finishing to process it as a directive or something like that. And it is not as trivial as you may think

Comment: It is not trivial - it is probably not feasible (in a reliable way) and certainly bad design. Seriously, why would you _"have to"_ use a directive with a child-directive that depends on the parent-directive's controller inside an `ng-view` ?

Comment: I have a menu directive that uses a template with a list of menuItem directives, and I use this menu directive inside my views. The menu directive controller is used to communicate between the menu directive and the menuItem directives

Comment: @GregoryBouteiller: But why use it inside an ng-view since it is going to be removed from the DOM ?

Comment: @GregoryBouteiller: I see it and I don't understand how it changes or explains anything. You are trying to add some stuff inside on `ngView` although `ngView`'s content gets replaced. It really does not make any sense (unless I am missing something - which...you know...I'm not :)).

Comment: You're missing the fact that, due to the use of wordpress via jade, I have content inside my ng-view for SEO and users who have disabled js. So when a user with js loads the page, that content generated in php inside ng-view is replaced but BEFORE it's interpreted by angularjs and this is when the error occurs...and should not.

Comment: And the purpose is not to add content inside ng-view for users with js. It's to provide content for SEO and users without js (if you also missed that point :))

Comment: @GregoryBouteiller: In that case you are doing it in the wrong way. If you are concerned about users without JS then Angular is definitely not the way to go. And SEO in Angular should also not be done that way (it's pointless anyway). But the most important point (which you are missing - and I am not) is that (you say) you are trying to add directives inside `ngView` for users that have no JS. If the user doesn't have JS how on earth do you plan to have Angular $compile and link those directives ? It is a JS framework as I am sure you know :)

Comment: I won't lose my time anymore to answer to your comments after that as they are patronizing but most of all non constructive regarding my problem: saying "you're wrong and I'm not" is useless. As I already explained, the problem occurs WHEN users WITH JS load the page with content in ng-view FOR users WITHOUT JS or FOR SEO and even if it is, in your point view, bad design ( in which case, it should have been interesting to describe your "right way" ), it's not normal that angularjs throws an error for that ( in fact, it seems to be a bug as similar cases are mentioned in issues on github )

Comment: Finally, I'm concerned about users without JS because I'm concerned about ALL users for a website. I'm well aware that AngularJS is JS as it is mentioned in the framework name. And last but not least, I have directives in my php pages ( that are used for ALL users ) because I use Jade for templating and I create only one template for both cases (with and without js).

Comment: @GregoryBouteiller: Fair enough. I don't want to lose my time with unconstructive comments either. Good luck with having your directives compiled for users without JS. Regarding SEO, please do post your results if you get any success, because everyone else seems to be doing it in other ways, so it would be interesting to have an easier alternative.